# How do I specify decimal and thousands separators for the numbers within a CSV Export?

Tags: php, csv

```
     $num_column = mysql_num_fields($view); 
     $csv_header = '';
     for($i = 0; $i < $num_column; $i++) {
         $csv_header .= '"' . mysql_field_name($view,$i) . '";';
     }  
     $csv_header .= "\r\n";

     $csv_row = '';   
     while($row = mysql_fetch_row($view)) {
         for($i = 0; $i < $num_column; $i++) {
            $csv_row .= '"' . $row[$i] . '";';
        }
        $csv_row .= "\r\n";
     }
```

I am currently creating a CSV file from a stored procedure on PHPMyadmin.
Here's a code snippet from where I am creating the export file.

I want to have decimal separators as a comma e.g (1,45) and thousands separators as a decimal point e.g (14.124).

I am aware of the number_format function but I am unsure as to how to apply it to ALL numbers within my generated CSV export.

Comment: Are you trying to output this via a stored proc, or via a PHP script? A stored procedure is an SQL script that the database executes.

Comment: Related: [fputcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) - Are you trying to roll your own CSV output? Why? `fputcsv` can turn arrays into CSV and let you set delimiters etc.

Comment: `number_format($number, 2, '.', ',');`-> what is $number here and from where you get that?

Comment: `mysql_fetch_row()` returns an array of strings, how do you know which of those are numbers? Maybe do it only for specific columns.

Comment: @RToyo The PHP script is outputting the CSV, pulling the data from a PHPMyAdmin stored procedure.

Comment: @AlivetoDie Sorry, I pasted that in and forgot to remove that line. Edited the question.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton I was struggling, so I found this solution online.

Comment: I've edited the code a lot. I now use fputcsv, should I re-ask the question or add the code snippet which may change some answers. I'm new to SO so I don't know the courtesy.

Comment: @DeanRaina new question please.

Comment: @DeanRaina I'm not trying to push my answer here, but you shouldn't start a new question unless your new code will actually change the question. This particular question is about how to automatically format a value for output, and not about how you should improve the creation of your CSV files. I'm not saying don't do it - it could affect the answers you get (eg someone might suggest you place all values in an array for output via fputcsv, and then run that array through array_map to format numbers)...But just try not to post different questions with minor/superfluous differences.

Comment: @RToyo thanks for the input, I will not add a new question. I was just wondering as to how I could display a different approach that does not correlate to my original question to people stuck in a similar situation.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume that you want to do this in PHP rather than in a stored proc.

First things first: do not use mysql_* functions. They are deprecated in PHP 5, and removed completely in PHP 7 - and for good reason. Look into mysqli or PDO. If you're not familiar with OOP in PHP, it might seem a little confusing, but it's really not too different from the mysql_* functions.

With that aside, I would suggest running each value through a function when you output it. You can either have that function format anything that looks like a number, or you use a white list to format specific columns that you know are numbers.

Here is an example all-inclusive function - you can trim it down to what you need. It will allow you to pass the value to be formatted, as well as an optional argument for the column name, and another optional argument for an array of columns that should be formatted as a number.

```
function format_number_output ($val, $col=false, $whitelist=array())
{
    // First, check if the column name was passed
    if ($col !== false && count($whitelist) > 0)
    {
        // Is this one of the columns that should be formatted?
        if (in_array($col, $whitelist) && is_numeric($val))
        {return number_format($val, 2, ',', '.');}
        // If not, then just return the original value
        else
        {return $val;}
    }

    // If the column name was not passed, then format anything that looks like a number
    else if (is_numeric($val))
    {return number_format($val, 2, ',', '.');}

    // Otherwise, just return the original value
    else
    {return $val;}
}
```

And you could test it out with different options:

```
// Returns "1234.56":
print format_number_output("1234.56", "actually_text", array("numeric_field", "another_numeric")); 
// Returns "1.234,56":
print format_number_output("1234.56", "numeric_field", array("numeric_field", "another_numeric")); 
// Returns "text":
print format_number_output("text", "numeric_field", array("numeric_field", "another_numeric")); 
// Returns "1.234,56":
print format_number_output("1234.56"); 
// Returns "text":
print format_number_output("text");
```

In addition, I would strongly suggest you take the advice of GrumpyCrouton and use [`fputcsv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php). The CSV format has so many stupid little gotchas that you don't want to deal with.

You could modify your code to have it work like this (I've left your mysql_fetch_array call - but again, learn to use PDO/mysqli ASAP before your project gets large and refactoring becomes difficult):

```
$fp = fopen("output.csv", "w");
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($view)) {
    $cur_row = array();
    for($i = 0; $i < $num_column; $i++) {
        $cur_row[] = format_number_output($row[$i]);
    }
    fputcsv($fp, $cur_row);
}
fclose($fp)
```

And if you wanted to go with the white-list approach, you could use mysql_fetch_array (or rather - the PDO/mysqli equivalent) to get the column names:

```
$fp = fopen("output.csv", "w");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($view)) {
    $cur_row = array();
    foreach ($row as $col=>$val) {
        $cur_row[] = format_number_output($val, $col, array("numeric_field", "another_numeric_field"));
    }
    fputcsv($fp, $cur_row);
}
fclose($fp)
```